# Please what is the meaning of the Deprecation_Warning message?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I used Perceptron from sklearn.linear_model for the first time and I got this message

"DeprecationWarning: n_iter parameter is deprecated in 0.19 and will be removed in 0.21. Use max_iter and tol instead.

DeprecationWarning"

while using the following code.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
ppn=Perceptron(n_iter=40, eta0= 0.1, random_state=1)
ppn.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
y_pred = ppn.predict(X_test_std)
```

Could somebody tell me what is the issue here ? Thank you

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about the message? It warns you that you should not use a certain feature because when you update the library it will be removed.

Comment: i dont know who downvoted you but ill upvote you because by the moment i got the error it didnt have the warning, and thanks to this i know i have to use max iter and tol instead which now ill have to... ugh... research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read up on the specification for `sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html#sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron):

> **max_iter** : int, optional
>
> The maximum number of passes over the training data (aka epochs). It
>   only impacts the behavior in the fit method, and not the partial_fit.
>   Defaults to 5. Defaults to 1000 from 0.21, or if tol is not None.
>
> New in version 0.19.
>
> **tol** : float or None, optional
>
> The stopping criterion. If it is not None, the iterations will stop
>   when (loss > previous_loss - tol). Defaults to None. Defaults to 1e-3
>   from 0.21.
>
> New in version 0.19.
>
> **n_iter** : int, optional
>
> The number of passes over the training data (aka epochs). Defaults to
>   None. Deprecated, will be removed in 0.21.
>
> Changed in version 0.19: Deprecated

Answer (score 1):

It's only a notification that in future versions this parameter (n_iter) will be removed by max_iter.

It's a good practice so replace it, so in future version your script will work fine.